# set target of button with link - materual-ui

Tags: material-ui

I am trying to get the button href from material-ui.com to open in an external self window if the link is external.

Wondering how this can be done.

```
<Button size="small" color="primary" href="https://example.com/" target="self">
                        Visit Website
                        </Button>
```

Normally we would code

```
<a href="http://link.com" target="_blank"> link </a>
```

Comment: Did you try `target="_blank"` in the button instead of self?

Answer (score -1):

Instead of Button, maybe you could try using Link component instead https://material-ui.com/components/links/

```
<Link
  component="button"
  variant="body2"
  onClick={() => {
    console.info("I'm a button.");
  }}
>
  Button Link
</Link>
```

Comment: Suggesting a different element does not answer the question.

Comment: How so, Link is the right component to use given that use case of wanting to use the target attribute.